# Send selector (reload) to current view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, selector

I have a reload-button in my `UINavigationController` that is supposed to send a `reload`-selector to the current loaded view, a.k.a the view on top. I can't figure out how I can achieve this.

I have no idea where to start, so if someone could give me a pointer, that would be great :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get controller that's on top of navigation stack via `topViewController` property in UINavigatiionController, so you'll get code something like (or you can get view from controller and send a message to it directly if you want):

```
UIViewController* topController = navigationController.topViewController;
if ([topController respondsToSelector:@selector(reload)]){
   [topController performSelector:@selector(reload)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[navigationController.topViewController.view reload];
```